# Compile iPhone only app to iPad device in Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

Is it possible to compile my iPhone app (which is developed for iPhone only) to my iPad with Xcode? I want to to this for presentation purposes, so I know it is not really compatible but I want to show it to a client and run it in 2x mode.

The iPad devices is attached in my provisioning profile.

When I try to compile it in Xcode it says:

> Xcode could not run using the selected device

In Xcode I choose: "iOS device" (the other options in this menu are: iPad 5.1 simulator and iPhone 5.1 simulator).

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, select Organizer and in the Devices section, having the iPad plugged thru usb cable, select 'Use for development'.
This way allows you to run the app directly in the iPad form Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have added the device id in iOS provisioning profile you are using in the project

Comment: Whooops, found it ;) Had to click the "use for development" in the organiser! Ik works now!